# Streaming a .txt via socket c++

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I need to send a txt file via socket connection when requested by client. The problem is I can't figure how to convert from binary format to ASCII. With this code the client receive only junk characters.

```
ifstream file;
char output [logfilesize];

file.open( "log.txt" );

file >> output;
send(socket, output, sizeof(output), 0);
cout << output << endl;

file.close
```

Sorry if the question have been asked multiple time but after reading all post I could not figure how to make it work.

Thank's!

---

Edit: Working code!

```
int lenght;
char * logf;
ifstream file;

file.open("log.txt");   
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
lenght = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
logf = new char [lenght];
file.read(logf, lenght);
file.close();

cout.write (logf, lenght);
send(soc,logf , lenght, 0);
delete[] logf;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sizeof(output)` will return the size of the original array you declared rather than the number of characters you read in via the stream operator. You can only use the stream in operator from the file stream if you know the file is text (i.e. you want to read a single delimited string). Else you should read the required number of bytes from the stream via the `read()` calls. If it is a string, then use the `strlen()` function to determine the length of the string (NOTE: this will not work for binary data).

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answers. Unfortunately, I still have a problem with send() The client is only receiving the first character of the document.

Comment: @user38586, hard to tell without knowing what the client code looks like.

Comment: The client for testing purpose is Netcat.

Comment: Also, I verified that lenght variable is returning the good amount of bytes. I suspect that it as something to do about a \0 byte missing at the end of the string? Not sure...

Comment: The problem is that in your new code, you are still passing in the `sizeof(lenght)` to the `send` call - you need to actually pass in the length that you read in!